# Vector Bender not translating

Tags: qgis-3, vector-layer

Based on other questions about how to "georeference" an image file, I took an SVG from our graphic designers, saved as a .dxf in Inkscape, and then imported into QGIS. I'm new to QGIS (we typically use ArcGIS but I can't import vectors there), so I could be trying to do something that another tool would be better for.

[image: Translation issues in Vector Bender]

The image above was taken after numerous attempts. I import the .dxf, turn it into a GeoPackage, give it the same projection as the Esri basemap I'm using, turn on editing, and then use Vector Bender. I have tried using just 1 point translations, 2 point translations/scales/rotation, 3 point affines, and 3+ point bends. I have tried these separately and in different combinations. I cannot seem to figure out the right set of steps to get the black outline to actually overlay with the United States geographically.

I know you cannot see it well that far zoomed out, but the black outline is a more simplified/"graphical" representation of the states as well as counties within Ohio. My end goal here is to get that into a shapefile that I can use to more quickly plot points/distances when we're outputting data requests.

Comment: Is there any special reason you don't use freely available shapefiles which contain these borders?

Comment: For our marketing or as a reference to help align geographically? If the former, I don't make the marketing decisions is the simple answer. My hands are tied there.

Comment: Probably marketing isn't aware of the data available? You could at least try to promote existing data to them.

Comment: While I appreciate you taking the time to read the question and offer feedback, your comments are not actually helpful toward a solution. The issue at hand isn't whether we are aware of already available data (we are, thank you). The issue is in trying to use a tool to manipulate vector layers in QGIS and being unable to get it to perform a translation.

Comment: Could you edit your question and include some more detail (ideally screenshots) about the steps you've followed to use Vector Bender?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Vector Bender, but linking to cwollett's answer, I would suggest to take data from GADM (Database of Global Administrative Areas https://gadm.org/index.html) in shapefile format, load into QGIS and use the 'Simplify Geometries tool' (under Vector > Geometry Tools). You'll get shapes with fewer vertices like in your screenshots. If you want to smooth your geometries, use the 'Smooth tool'. As your end goal is to have a "shapefile that I can use to more quickly plot points/distances when we're outputting data requests", you should be able to continue measuring your points/distances and get your layer collection into a printable map layout.